# Postgresql - How to rank this data?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, rank

Here is my data:

```
client_addr |  start  
------------+-----------
 1.2.3.4    |   12:54:06
 1.2.3.4    |   12:55:00
 5.6.7.8    |   12:54:06
 5.6.7.8    |   13:00:00
 5.6.7.8    |   11:00:00
 9.9.9.9    |   14:00:00
```

I want to sort it and rank it like this:

```
  RK | client_addr |    start  
-----+-------------+-----------
  1  |  1.2.3.4    |  12:54:06
  1  |  5.6.7.8    |  11:00:00
  1  |  9.9.9.9    |  14:00:00
  2  |  1.2.3.4    |  12:55:00
  2  |  5.6.7.8    |  12:54:06
  3  |  5.6.7.8    |  13:00:00
```

I have tried this

```
SELECT 
    rank() over (order by start ASC) as RK,
    client_addr,
    start
FROM
    my_table
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT
  rank() OVER (PARTITION BY client_addr ORDER BY start) AS RK,
  client_addr,
  start
FROM my_table
ORDER BY RK, inet(client_addr)
```

Output:

```
| RK | CLIENT_ADDR |                     START |
|----|-------------|---------------------------|
|  1 |     1.2.3.4 | January, 01 1970 12:54:06 |
|  1 |     5.6.7.8 | January, 01 1970 11:00:00 |
|  1 |     9.9.9.9 | January, 01 1970 14:00:00 |
|  2 |     1.2.3.4 | January, 01 1970 12:55:00 |
|  2 |     5.6.7.8 | January, 01 1970 12:54:06 |
|  3 |     5.6.7.8 | January, 01 1970 13:00:00 |
```

Note you'll have to user the `inet` function if you want the IP address `10.12.13.14` to be sorted after the `9.9.9.9` instead of after `1.2.3.4` (see the fiddle below).

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8c862/1).

Comment: +1. Better yet: use the [`inet`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-net-types.html#DATATYPE-INET) data type to begin with : `CREATE TABLE my_table(client_addr inet, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, is not possible to be done in one single query, but it is easy to do with [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) and [cte](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html). Maybe an easiest query can be created, but this one works.

```
create table my_table (client_addr varchar, start time);
insert into my_table values ('1.2.3.4', '12:54:06'), ('1.2.3.4','12:55:00'), ('5.6.7.8', '12:54:06'), ('5.6.7.8', '13:00:00'), ('5.6.7.8', '11:00:00'), ('9.9.9.9', '14:00:00');

with t as (select rank() over (partition by client_addr order by start) as RK, client_addr, start from my_table)
select RK, client_addr, start from t order by RK;
```